# PythonでPandasを使って行を追加する方法について

Tags: python, python3

**やりたいこと**
PythonでBook1のエクセルに横方向から縦方向へ行を追加したいです。

Book1のエクセル

```
created_at,title,messageId
2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611
2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612
```

実現したい内容

```
List=['1','2']

#リストから１要素ずつループ
for item in List:
 print(item)
```

のリストを読み込んだ後に
contentの列に対して１行ずつ横方向から縦方向へ１行目から行を追加したいです。
**※毎回リストは1,2の数字ではないです。変化します。**

```
created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,test
2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,test
```

```
List=['1455','1215']の場合

created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,test
2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,test
```

```
List=['1455','1215','1217']3個の場合

created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,test
2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,test
,,,test
```

```
List=['1455','1215','1217','1218']4個の場合

created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,test
2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,test
,,,test
,,,test
```

現在の結果
appendやlocを使って３行目から行は追加されますが、
実現したい結果のように１行目から追加されないです。

1行目から追加させる方法ありますでしょうか。

もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけますか。
お手数ですが、ご確認をお願いします。

```
created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,
2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,
,,,test
,,,test
```

コード

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

#ファイル名
Book1=r"test.xlsx"

#Book1読み込み
df1 = pd.read_excel(Book1)

List=['1','2']

#リストから１要素ずつループ
for item in List:
 print(item)

 #行を追加
 #df1 = pd.DataFrame({'content': ["test"]})

 #df1 =  df1.append(df2)
 df1.loc[item,'content']="test"

 #エクセルへ保存
 df1.to_excel(Book1, sheet_name="sheet", index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: "行", "列", "行数" の表現がごっちゃになっている気がします。正確な表現を心掛けてみてください。

Comment: 失礼しました。修正いたします。

Comment: List=['1','2']とdf1との関連性が分かりません。['1','2']はもしかしてdf1の1行目、2行目を意味していますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
List=['1','2']は1行目、2行目意味しております。ただ毎回List=['1','2']ではいため"1234","2134"特定に変更します。

Comment: @Happy さん、追記された`List=['1455','1215']`の関連ですが、今の処理結果だけではなく、望む結果は何か、も示してください。また今までの説明だと、`List`の中身(値)にかかわらずデータの最初の行から`test`という文字列(これも`List`の中身との関係が不明ですが)を追記しようとしているように見えますが、それは本当ですか？ そして例として2行のDataFrameと2個のリストという数の同じ組み合わせばかり説明されていますが、例えば3行のDataFrameに5個のリストとか、4行のDataFrameに2個のリスト等の数が違う場合は発生するのか、その場合はどうしたいのか、といったことも考慮して説明を追記してください。

Comment: @kunif さん、コメントありがとうございます。2個以上の場合実現したい結果を記載しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate`を使ってリストの要素数を取得して実現したい結果になりました。
参考ページ
[Python, enumerateの使い方: リストの要素とインデックスを取得](https://note.nkmk.me/python-enumerate-start/)

#リストから１要素ずつループ

```
for item in List:
 print(item)
```

へ変更

**#リスト要素数取得**

```
for idx, item in enumerate(List):
    df1.loc[idx,'content']="test"
```

全体コード

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

#ファイル名
Book1=r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"

#Book1読み込み
df1 = pd.read_excel(Book1)

List=['1213','3134']

#enumerateリスト要素数取得
for idx, item in enumerate(List):
    df1.loc[idx,'content']="test"


    #エクセルへ保存
    df1.to_excel(Book1, sheet_name="sheet", index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

> created_at,title,messageId,content
> 2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,test
> 2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,test

上記DataFrameを

> created_at,title,messageId,content
> 2022-06-16T04:30:08.328Z,test1,2335791611,test
> 2022-06-17T04:30:08.328Z,test2,2335791612,test

にしたいのであれば、

```
for i in List:
    df1.loc[int(i)-1, "content"] = "test"
```

で良いかと思います。

---

質問の追記を受けての回答です。

```
df1.loc[0:len(List), "content"] = "test"
```

```
for i in range(len(List)):
    df1.loc[i, "content"] = "test"
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
上記の方法で行うと、１行目からcontentの列に書き込むことできますが、リストが`List=['1455','1215']`が変わる場合、１行目から書き込みできないです。毎回リストは`1``2`ではないです。特定のIDに変化します。その場合1行目から書き込むことができますでしょうか。もし分かれば、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: @Happy さん、`List=['1','2']`の時と`List=['1455','1215']`の時の両方で、何処に何を書き込むか(そして別の部分には書き込まないか)の例を(何故そうなるか/何故そうしたいかも含めて)追加した方が良いでしょう。やりたい事の全体像がイマイチ不明確な感じです。

Comment: @kunifさん、回答ありがとうございます。両方の時の結果を質問内容に記載しました。お手隙の際にご確認をお願い致します。

Comment: 「数字が変化しても1行目から書き込むようにしたいです。」ということはListの要素数に意味があり、要素の値そのものには”今回の処理においては”意味がない、ということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: @merinoさん、コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りです。リストの値は今回の処理におていは意味ないです。リストの要素数だけです。

Answer (score 1):

やりたいことは、`df['content'] = content_list`みたいなことではないでしょうか。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
    columns=['created_at', 'title', 'messageId']
)
content_list = ['A', 'B']

df['content'] = content_list 

print(df)
```

```
  created_at title messageId content
0          a     b         c       A
1          d     e         f       B
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。やりたいことはリストの内容の中身関係なく、入っている要素を１個ずつループさて、contetの内容を元に1行目から書き込みしたいです。現在だ3行目目から書き込まれてしまいます。もし分かれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

Book1 = 'test.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(Book1)
List = ['1', '2']
List = [int(i) - 1 for i in List] # zero-based indexing
df1.loc[List, 'content'] = 'test'
df1.to_excel(Book1, sheet_name='sheet', index=False, header=True)
```

[image]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。質問内容にも記載しましたが`List=['1455','1215']の場合`
indexエラーが表示されます。毎回リスト1,2ではないです。`List=['1455','1215']`の時に１行目から書き込むことが可能でしょうか。もし分かれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: エラーの原因はおそらく1455 行目と 1215 行目が存在しないからなのでしょう。一行目から書き込むことは可能ですが、`List` の意味は一体何なのでしょう？

Comment: `List`はループの要素数（回数）だけをしめしております。中身は毎回変化するので、リストの値は特に意味ないです。

Comment: 「List=['1','2']は1行目、2行目意味しております。」っていう表現は誤解の元ですよ。。。

Comment: 失礼しました。間違えて記載しました。

Comment: 質問内容をもう少しわかりやすくにしました。上記の処理可能でしょうか。もし分かれば教えていただけると幸いです。